# Featured image not updating (file name, not cached image)

Tags: post-thumbnails

Using the Twenty Twenty theme. I switched out the Featured Image on a page for a new image. While the new image is displayed properly within the page editor, the page itself tries to fetch the *old* filename, and returns a 404 because it cannot find it at that location.

I'm not new to front-end development but I have so far not had to deep dive into WordPress and PHP. Clearly something is not working as expected here. I'd love to fix the function that updates the user-facing page when the page editor makes a change, but I'm not sure where to look in the theme to correct this.

When I looked up this problem, I found that the wrong image being displayed is usually a browser caching issue. However, since it's attempting to fetch by the wrong filename, refreshing the cache doesn't work. If the page compiler itself is cached, not sure how to force that to update to match the page editor.

For now, I am going to edit the filename to match the old file, just to get this fixed. That's more of a workaround than a fix and I would like a better idea of what's going on.

Thanks!

Comment: This is most likely a caching problem that has to do with either your host, or a plugin. WordPress itself shows updates immediately, but some hosts and some plugins cache pretty hard.

Comment: @WebElaine That could be it! I noticed the ONLY plugin is LiteSpeed. I tried a "purge all" but to no avail. I hope removing the plugin doesn't leave any residual gunk.